# If the requirements can change in future, is it a good idea to pull the business rules out of the code into a custom rule engine?

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns, refactoring, rule-engine

We have a requirement such that Users need to be presented different facts based on some constraints.

Similar Hypothetical Example

- If User belongs to Australia and earns more than 10k$ then show XYZ view of data/facts
- If User belongs to USA and earns less than 5k$ then show ABC view of data/facts
- ...
- ...

Now we can either,
    keep this mapping in the user model and have these business rules in the code 
or 
    we can pull these rules out into a JSON or a DSL where we can simply change the rule without having to deploy the code for every single change.

We dont know how frequently these rules will change.

I have read arguments for and against the idea of a custom mini rule engine.

Arguments for:

1. Every small change will not require a deployment
2. All the rules related to this specific functionality are at one place (probably) making it easier to get an overview

Arguments against:

1. (Martin Fowler article) It will become difficult to reason about your code
2. Anemic Data model anti-pattern
3. Over time it will be difficult to manage these rules
4. Conflicts between rules or the chance of some facts not belonging to any of

Comment: I suggest to wait until you know how often you need to change the values.  Premature optimization should be avoided.

Comment: Apply YAGNI: You Ain't Gonna Need It. The fact that you're talking about a requirement _change_ says that the functionality _isn't_ needed today.

Answer (score 2):

In general it depends on your use case. Looking at the examples you have provided it looks like an excellent application of a rules engine. By externalising that logic you'll make your application more declarative, easier to maintain, and will deliver value to your users faster.

In your case this is the key statement:

> We dont know how frequently these rules will change.

That suggests that you really need to externalize that logic either to a rules engine or a DSL of your choice. If you don't you'll be signing up to deploy new code every time those rules do change.

Your examples as written are pretty classic examples of ProductionRules
https://martinfowler.com/dslCatalog/productionRule.html
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Production_system_(computer_science)

There are many good open source and commercial rules engines available. I'd consider those before creating a custom DSL. The logic you've written matches very well with those systems.

Some of the technical downsides of rules engines and DSLs are:

- Rules systems can be difficult to test
- You have to carefully design the inputs and outputs to your rules
- You'll need to understand, document, and integrate another tool or custom DSL parser
- Building rules is a different mental model than some developers are used to and it can take time to do it well

Comment: *you'll be signing up to deploy new code every time those rules do change* So? Modern applications are frequently deployed several times a day. Making sure that the code is clean should provide appropriate hooks if future expansion is needed.

Comment: Sure lots of applications are deployed several times a day and it is a great practice. Does that mean you don't make your applications configurable or extensible? Or that declarative business logic isn't valuable? The ability to deploy quickly doesn't excuse bad design. And putting the ability to deploy rules in the hands of business users is in many cases (not all) the right approach.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong having business logic abstracted. And *declarative* rules seem appropriate in your scenario. One should be able to extract a - human readable - report, showing the business logic, the rules applied.

So the first stage would be the requirements, what you would like as product.
This can become extra code/modeling without impeding on the existent code base.

Do not start in the wild: do not search a solution library, when the problem and solution are unclear. Often a "solution framework" is applied, and the problem modeled after that. With much boiler plate code and not exactly matching what you actually would want.

At this stage you probably could make a simple prototype of a do-it-yourself rule engine. Maybe even make a fast and rough prototype. Then look for existing rule engines, and make prototypes. Preferably not on your application, but using Test-Driven-Development in unittests.

A bad idea is to immediately leave the rules definition maintenance to the end admin users. Such functionality has implications: missing test staging, working on the production system, versioning, technical qualifications of end users like big integrative picture.

*As a last remark: this might have been something for the Software Engineering forum.*